# Horizontally center TextView inside ImageView and there is another view next to Imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Hi I want to build UI as below
[image]

I want to center imageview above textview at the same time there is another view next to imagview dash line I am not able to do this.

Currently I am using RelativeLayout. Any idea how this can be done?

Following is XML

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivnumberfill"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_otp_fill" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivfirstdiv"
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ivnumberfill"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivnumberfill"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivnumberfill"
            android:src="@drawable/stroke_divider" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivotp"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivfirstdiv"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/otp_process_circle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivseconddiv"
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ivotp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivotp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivotp"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke_divider" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivprofile"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivseconddiv"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/otp_process_circle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvnumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ivnumberfill"
            android:alig="@id/ivnumberfill"
            android:text="Mobile Number"
            android:textColor="?colorAccent"
            android:textSize="11sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post what you're trying already?

Comment: added xml code please check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html), you should really learn it and use it instead of Relative Layout, it's more flexible and less computation consuming. Here is my layout, is it also more flexible - you can just move guideline and everything moves with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="24dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivnumberfill"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivotp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/plane" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivotp"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivprofile"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivnumberfill"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/plane" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivprofile"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivotp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/plane" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivfirstdiv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
            android:src="@drawable/line"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivotp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivnumberfill"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivseconddiv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
            android:src="@drawable/line"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivprofile"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivotp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline2" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvnumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Mobile Number"
            android:textColor="?colorAccent"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivnumberfill"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ivnumberfill"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivnumberfill" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvotp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="OTP"
            android:textColor="?colorAccent"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivotp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ivotp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivotp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvprofile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Profile"
            android:textColor="?colorAccent"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ivprofile"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ivprofile"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivprofile" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: this is how it looks]

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use Constraint layout for this just simple drag and drop and it will give you your desired layout.

sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@color/thirdColor">

    <View
        android:layout_width="272dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/firstColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.333" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.123"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.22"
        app:srcCompat="@color/secondColor" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.897"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.22"
        app:srcCompat="@color/secondColor" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.22"
        app:srcCompat="@color/secondColor" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Sample Code"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.535"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.741" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Sample Code"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.971"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.729" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Sample Code"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.063"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.729" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

sample output, change icons and background accordingly.

[image]